# Obtener datos de consulta MySQL para imprimir en HTML

Tags: php, html, sql, checkbox

Dispongo de un **formulario HTML** donde quiero mostrar una serie de datos obtenidos de una **consulta en MySQL** mediante SQL.

**Consulta:**

```
    static public function obtenerAccesoriosPorCabana($idcabana){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT a.idaccesorio, a.descripcion FROM accesorios AS a, cabanasaccesorios AS ca WHERE ca.idcabana=$idcabana AND ca.idaccesorio=a.idaccesorio;";
        $registro = $ejecucion->query($sql);
        //Creamos un array para almacenar los accesorios.
        $misaccesorios = array();
        //Recorremos el array y añadimos en él los accesorios mediante array_push.
        while($datos = $registro->fetch()){
            array_push($misaccesorios, $datos);
        }
        return $misaccesorios; //Devuelve un array asociativo.
    }
```

**Prueba funcionamiento método obtenerAccesoriosPorCabana():**

```
    $accesorios = BD::obtenerAccesoriosPorCabana(2);
    foreach ($accesorios as $a){
        echo $a["idaccesorio"]. " ".$a["descripcion"]."<br/><br/>";
    }
```

Todo OK.

**Código HTML:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="modificar" id="modificar" method="POST">
    <center>
        <h3><b>Accesorios:</b></h3><br/>
        <?php 
        $objeto_accesorios = BD::obtenerAccesoriosPorCabana($_GET["idcabana"]);
        $num_accesorios = BD::contarAccesorios();
        for($i=1; $i<=$num_accesorios; $i++){
            if(in_array($i, $objeto_accesorios)){
                echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' value=<?php echo $i; ?>' id=<?php $i ?>' name='accesorios' checked>";
            }else{
                echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' value=<?php echo $i; ?>' id=<?php $i ?>' name='accesorios'";
            }
        }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Modificar" id="modificar" name="modificar" />
    </center>
</form>
```

**Preguntas:**

¿Por qué no se me muestran los accesorios con su checkbox correspondiente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los nombres se obtienen de la consulta: $accesorios["descripcion"], los nombres coinciden con los nombres de las imágenes "imagenes/xxxxx.png".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu función para obtener accesorios por cabaña no devuelve un array asociativo. Devuelve un array de arrays. Si quieres que devuelva un array asociativo, tendrías que hacer:

```
 $misaccesorios = [];
 while($datos = $registro->fetch()){
    $misaccesorios[$datos['idaccesorio']]=$datos['descripcion'];    
 }
 return $misaccesorios; //Esto SÍ devuelve un array asociativo.
```

La lógica tiene otros supuestos débiles. Por ejemplo, `BD::contarAccesorios();` te devuelve el total de accesorios disponibles,  pero no contempla el caso que en la tabla de accesorios haya IDs no consecutivos.